# Conditional arguments in Python function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, coding-style, arguments

Is there a way pass arguments conditionally in Python (I use Python 2.7)?

As an example, this code gives 2 or 3 arguments depending if the 3rd argument exists in a dictionary.

```
if "arg3" in my_dict:
    my_method(
        my_dict[arg1],
        my_dict[arg2],
        my_dict[arg3],
    )
else:
    my_method(
        my_dict[arg1],
        my_dict[arg2],
    )
```

I think it looks redundant to write it this way. I've seen some info on `argparse`, which I think would look like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(my_dict[arg1])
parser.add_argument(my_dict[arg2])
if arg3 in my_dict:
    parser.add_argument(my_dict[arg3])
args = parser.parse_args()

my_method(args)
```

I don't really like this method either, as it needs an import and is hard to read.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
my_method(
    my_dict[arg1],
    my_dict[arg2],
    my_dict[arg3] if arg3 in my_dict,
)
```

Or any other way I am missing, that would be simple and clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it like that:

```
my_method(my_dict[arg1], my_dict[arg2], my_dict.get(arg3, None))
```

You might want to change the `my_method` to adapt for this; maybe something like `def my_method(*args):`.

For more info on the `.get()` dictionary method take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey).

This solution is definitely *uglier* (acc to the Pythonic standards of beauty) than the one provided by @e4c5 but does not require the function variables to have the same name as the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your method signature is

```
def my_method(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    print ('arg1',arg1,'arg2',arg2,'arg3',arg3)
```

Then simply replace all those if/else blocks with

```
my_method(**dictionary)
```

For example

```
 d = {'arg3':11, 'arg2':22, 'arg1':3}
```

the above will produce

```
arg1 3 arg2 22 arg3 11
```

This behaviour is brought to by `**kwargs` there are quite a few good tutorials on it on the web. Here's one from [digial ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3) (I am not affiliated)

Comment: how does this work given that `dictionaries` are not ordered?

Comment: That is the nature of kwargs

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It depends on the keyword arguments having the same names as the `dict` keys, in which case the order in which you provide the keyword arguments is irrelevant. This answer greatly depends on how `my_method` is defined, though.

Comment: Oh I see.. So the function variables have to be the same as the dictionary keys. nice!

Comment: I like your answer a lot, and it fits my question, but actually I also have arguments that are from outside of `my_dict` as well in the call, so this solution would not work for me, while the `.get(arg3, None)` will always work.

Answer (score 0):

Both @Ev.Kounis and @e4c5 provide good answers. As far the attempt you made in the question, you are only missing a valid conditional expression.

```
my_method(
    my_dict[arg1],
    my_dict[arg2],
    my_dict[arg3] if arg3 in my_dict else None,
)
```

which is, practically speaking, the same as @Ev.Kounis proposed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I would consider changing my_method to take in a dict if you know that you will be passing in a dict each time.

```
def my_method(d):
    a1 = d[arg1]
    a2 = d[arg2]
    a3 = d[arg3] if 'arg3' in d else None
    ...
```

Otherwise, the other answers are also valid.